# How do I identify the cell selected in a Quasar table?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

How do I identify the cell selected in a Quasar table?

My goal is that once I identify the cell selected, if the user clicks on a custom button, I pass the selected cell information to a pop up page.

Note I'm not using the row selection checkboxes.

we want to be able to select multiple cells from a given column in a quasar table. I believe that this will take a custom selection capability.

Comment: Do you mean when a user clicks on the row?

Comment: when the user clicks on a row, it would identify the row and the column....so not just the row. If only the row is possible, please share that as well.

Comment: we want to be able to select multiple cells from a given column in a quasar table. I believe that this will take a custom selection capability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive the selection using the data `index`. Please refer the following codepen for multiple row selection.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrNBpV

And for cell selection refer this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNrdyL?editors=1010

try this

```
  <q-td key="desc" :props="props" v-for="col in props.cols" :key="col.name" @click.native="selectRow(props.row.__index,col.name)" :class="selected.hasOwnProperty(props.row.__index) && selected[props.row.__index].indexOf(col.name)!=-1?'bg-grey-2':''">
              {{ props.row[col.field] }}
            </q-td>
```

Comment: Thank you @patel-pratik, that's really awesome. Is there a way to dynamically have the 'name' as a variable instead of saying ```"selectRow(props.row.__index,'name')"```?       We have a lot of columns and I thought maybe I can have it dynamically set.

Comment: Awesome thank you @patel-pratik, this is super helpful. Is it also possible to hold shift or something to be able to select multiple cells in one column at once?

Comment: please do share if you think it's possible allow multi select by holding a keyboard button and selecting multiple cells in one column

Comment: sorry but i have no idea about this. But I think you can use mousedown event for this.

Comment: Patel, where can I get get the list of events?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rpe/ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#System-Modifier-Keys links